# BigQuery - running count and split functions together

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to run a count on the result of the *split* functions. The query below shows an example:

```
select a.name, 
  count(if(split(b.name,",")='test',null,1)) > 0 hasTest,
  from (select * from (select 'test,this' as name) a left join (select '2' as name) b on  
  a.name=b.name)
```

This query yields an error: `SELECT clause has mix of aggregations 'hasTest' and fields 'a.name' without GROUP BY clause`

If I change the `hasTest` column to be an integer instead of boolean, so that:

```
count(if(split(b.name,",")='test',null,1))
```

The query succeeds.

For some reason *BigQuery* knows how to evaluate the count function (working on a nested element created in place, therefore not requiring a group by clause), but is not able to take the same  capability when the count is wrapped in a boolean operator.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just an unclear error message.
The problem here seems to be with the data type of null. bq needs you to define nulls data type. The default null data type is boolean. If you don't define it, there is a mix of data types in the same field.